# Photo Lens does not work

Tags: unity, lenses

The new photo lens in Ubuntu's 12.10 dash does not work for me. It simple shows nothing. All other lenses work like a charm. I have not switched off any sources in 'Privacy Settings'.

Yes, I have photos in my photo folder. No, I haven't installed Shotwell.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that the Photo-Lens only works with Shotwell.

Comment: please elaborate here, others users may benefit from your findings. include workarounds, suggested solutions etc., thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found is that you have to import in shotwell and then after this log out and then back in again and the photos are there.

Answer (score 0):

The photos lens works with Photo imported in Shotwell and photos from Flickr, Facebook and Picasa online accounts (see System Settings -> Online Accounts).